# Is there a single word for two phrases which are synonymous with one another?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, phrases, synonyms, vocabulary

Is there a single concise word for two phrases which have the same or nearly the same meanings as one another? Lately, I have found myself Googling phrases like "loath to admit synonym" or "take for example synonym," in the hopes of findings phrases of a similar construction and of a similar meaning. This feels imprecise.

Though Webster's Dictionary defines a synonym as:

*one of two or more words or expressions of the same language that have the same or nearly the same meaning in some or all senses*

I can't help but feel as though I am not living up to my full Googling potential. Any help?

Comment: They might be called *phrase replacements*, but when I search for that I, like you, don’t find a handy reference for common phrases.  Why not use a thesaurus on the individual words. For loath you might find *averse*. Then you’d have “I am averse to admitting ...”

Comment: I don’t understand you objection to the word synonym. Just look up the phrases (put them in quotes).

Comment: @Xanne Though 'synonym' correctly covers phrases (and even broader constructions), if one is looking for a multi-word synonym of say 'take the biscuit' one will struggle using 'synonym' as a search item. // I discovered a reference book on 'phrasal synonyms', but can't find where I stored the information!

Comment: Ah ... rediscovered it: 'The Thesaurus of English Idioms' by G L Nagy.

Comment: **synonymous phrases**

Comment: **phrasal synonyms**: 'It is, therefore, sometimes difficult and a matter of subjective judgement to decide where a phrasal synonym ends and an explanation begins.' (A History of Roget's Thesaurus : Origins, Development, and ... Werner Hüllen · 2003)

Comment: Some online thesauruses like Merriam-Webster or thesaurus.com will give results for short phrases. M-W uses the word "synonyms" e.g. ["make amends"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/make%20amends%20for).

Comment: No, there isn't any such term, for the same reason that we use phrases so much. You can't have a single word for everything you can imagine.

Comment: @JohnLawler The members of The Python Foundation strongly disagree.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid repeating synonym, you could use equivalent(s).

**equivalent** (n.)

> A word, expression, sign, etc., of equivalent meaning or import. OED

---

> For instance, the Italian idiom *far come l'angelo di Badia* (lit.
> behave like the angel of Badia, i.e., the angel on the dome of Badia,
> in Florence, which keeps changing the position according to the
> direction of the wind, 'keep changing opinions') possesses two
> **idiomatic equivalents** in the Polish language, both in the form of similes. [Roberta Corrigan; *Formulaic Language*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Formulaic_Language_Distribution_and_hist/AyqQYkx9HToC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=possesses%20two%20idiomatic%20equivalents)

Comment: It's a very broad hypernym, with this stipulative definition a rare usage.

Comment: It can be. However, with words and phrases, we aim for A = B knowing the best we can do is A ≈ B. The narrow bull's-eye is equivalency. *Equivalent* is also listed as a synonym for [*synonym*](https://thesaurus.yourdictionary.com/synonym)

Comment: It's a very broad hypernym, **_with this stipulative definition a rare usage_**.